# Save Windows Form Data to Database Using Button

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am making a Windows Form application with C# to take tracking numbers that are scanned into the text box and saves them to a DB. I have the form designed and a DB set up but I can't figure out how to get the form to save to the DB.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PackageTracker
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void confirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //parses tracking number to determine the shipping method/carrier. Places result in shipType text box
            shipTypeTextBox.Text = determineShipType(trackingNumTextBox.Text);


            //save to DB
            this.Validate();
            this.packagesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.packagesDataSet);

            //display info sent to DB
            AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Tracking Number: " + trackingNumTextBox.Text + "\n" +
                                    "Ship Type: " + shipTypeTextBox.Text + "\n" +
                                    "Ship Date: " + dateDateTimePicker.Value, "Test", 1000);

            //clear fields to ready form for next scan
            trackingNumTextBox.Text = "";
            shipTypeTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        catch(IndexOutOfRangeException err)
        {
            string errMess = string.Format("Error: {0}", err.Source);
            MessageBox.Show( errMess, "Error");
        }
    }

    public string determineShipType(string tNum)
    {
        if (tNum[0] == '1')
        {
            if (tNum.Substring(8, 2) == "YW")
                return "UPS Surepost";
            return "UPS";
        }
        if (tNum[0] == '4')
        {
            if(tNum.Substring(8, 4) == "9400")
                return "USPS FCM";
            if (tNum.Substring(8, 4) == "9405")
                return "USPS Priortiy Mail";
        }
        return "Unknown Ship Type";
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I didn't write the Validate() method. I copied the code automatically generated by VS in another app that used the BindingNavigation control. Here is the code that is shown when I right click it and use Go To Definition:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Verifies the value of the control losing focus by causing the System.Windows.Forms.Control.Validating
//     and System.Windows.Forms.Control.Validated events to occur, in that order.
//
// Returns:
//     true if validation is successful; otherwise, false. If called from the System.Windows.Forms.Control.Validating
//     or System.Windows.Forms.Control.Validated event handlers, this method will
//     always return false.
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public bool Validate();
```

This code was all generated by VS when I dragged the Packages table from my DB on to the form:

```
private PackagesDataSet packagesDataSet;
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource packagesBindingSource;
private PackagesDataSetTableAdapters.PackagesTableAdapter packagesTableAdapter;
private PackagesDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager tableAdapterManager;
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code in `Validate()`.

Comment: This isn't enough information for anyone to help you, where is your Validate method definition?

Comment: This is still a mystery to me (and probably others). What is `packagesBindingSource` and where is it being updated? You'll need to explain how you expect this to work like "when I click the button a sproc should be called". Right now we just have a bunch of variables shown but nothing showing the mapping between your database and application.

Comment: This is mostly code generated by Visual Studio. I dragged the table from the DB on to the form and it generated a lot of it's own code. All the code under the save to DB comment is created by VS.

Comment: Please post the whole class of your form(form1.cs or whatever you called it). That will help us.

Comment: Ok, so based on what you've posted, how are you hooking up your dataset/binding source back to your database?

Comment: I added the DB via the Solution Explorer(Right click > Add item > Local DB). Then I created the table by double clicking on the DB in the solution Explorer and added a table via the Server Explorer window. I opened the Data Sources window navigated to the table I created  right clicked the arrow next to it and picked "Details" then I dragged the table on to the form. I copied the code under the save to DB comment form another app that I created the same exact way (I followed instructions form a book). The only difference is in the first app a BindingNavigator control was also created.